# Podman - How to search by latest tags

Tags: wordpress, podman

When I run the following command in Debian, from the terminal...

```bash
podman search --list-tags docker.io/wordpress --limit 10

- it will list the following results :

NAME                         TAG
docker.io/library/wordpress  3
docker.io/library/wordpress  3.9
docker.io/library/wordpress  3.9.1
docker.io/library/wordpress  3.9.2
docker.io/library/wordpress  4
docker.io/library/wordpress  4-apache
docker.io/library/wordpress  4-fpm
docker.io/library/wordpress  4-fpm-alpine
docker.io/library/wordpress  4-php5.6
docker.io/library/wordpress  4-php5.6-apache
```

But when I go to docker.io, [the latest versions for WordPress is 6.3.1](https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress)

How can I get podman to list the latest tag versions of WordPress, starting from the top of the list?